# Obj-C Function Parameters

Tags: objective-c, function, parameters

How can I send parameters to my function?

```
- (void)alertURL {
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    alertURL(url);
    return YES;
}
```

If there is anything else wrong, please tell me :)

Comment: You should read apple's free Objective-C Introduction: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html As @bbum pointed out that is not a function at all. Objective-C does have functions, so it's important to understand the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to define what you call a function, which is a method in Obj-C talk, is to add a colon and the type in parentheses and the parameter variable name.

Then to invoke the method, you use the square brackets.

```
- (void)alertURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Old C function: alertURL(url);

    [self alertURL:url];
    return YES;
}
```

Functions are still supported, they're just regular C functions, which mean they're not associated with any object. What you want to be doing is sending a message to the object using the square brackets. It's an Obj-C thing, you'll get used to it.

Answer (score 4):

First, that isn't a function, that is an *instance method*.  Instance methods can take arguments:

```
- (void)alertURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
```

Or, if you wanted to add more than one:

```
- (void)alertURL:(NSURL *)url ensureSecure: (BOOL) aFlag
{
    NSLog(@"%@",url);
    if (aFlag) { ... secure stuff ... }
}
```

Secondly, you don't call a method using function call syntax, you call it via method call syntax:

```
[self alertURL: anURL];
[self alertURL: anURL ensureSecure: YES];
```

Finally, the question indicates that you don't yet understand Objective-C.  No worries -- we were all there once.  Apple provides an excellent [introduction to Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just like what you would do in C.

```
void alertURL(NSURL* url) {
  NSLog(@"%@",url);
}
```